# PHP temperature converter form using SWITCH and POST coming up blank after hitting submit

Tags: php, html, forms

I am trying to make a temperature converter using a form and PHP and using SWITCH case. I believe I am close to a solution, however when I hit the submit button, my page goes blank and I am not seeing my echo statement.  Here is my code:

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST['convertTemp']))

{

switch('$convertTemp'){

    case 'FtoC':
        $newTemp = (($tEmp - 32)* (5/9));
        break;

    case 'FtoK':
       $newTemp = (($tEmp - 32)* (5/9) + 273.15);
        break;

    case 'KtoF':
       $newTemp = (($tEmp - 273.15)* (9/5) + 32);
        break;

     case 'KtoC':
       $newTemp = ($tEmp - 273.15);
        break;

    case 'CtoK':
       $newTemp = ($tEmp + 273.15);
        break;

    case 'CtoF':
       $newTemp = (($tEmp * 9/5) + 32);
        break;      
  echo " <h2 align='center'>The initial temperature was" . $tEmp . "and the converted temperature is:" . $newTemp . "/h2>";    

}
}else{
    echo'




<html>
<body>

<h1 align="center">Convert a Temperature</h1> 

    <form align="center" method="POST">

        Enter the tempurature you wish to convert:<input type="number" name="tEmp">

        <h2>Convert temperature from: </h2>
        <input type="radio" name="convertTemp" value="FtoC"> Farenheit to Celcius <br>
        <input type="radio" name="convertTemp" value="FtoK"> Farenheit to Kelvin <br>
        <input type="radio" name="convertTemp" value="KtoF"> Kelvin to Farenheit <br>
        <input type="radio" name="convertTemp" value="KtoC"> Kelvin to Celcius <br>
        <input type="radio" name="convertTemp" value="CtoK"> Celcius to Kelvin <br>
        <input type="radio" name="convertTemp" value="CtoF"> Celcius to Farenheit <br>

    <input type="submit" value="Convert Tempurature!">

    </form>



    </body>
    ';

    }

?>
```

Comment: `switch('$convertTemp'){` should be `switch($_POST['convertTemp']){`

Comment: @Nick, I don't think this is a duplicate - the quotes didn't cause an issue (they properly used double quotes within single quotes - and yes, the variable was surrounded by single quotes, but that's not what caused the echo to fail - as was their original question).

Comment: @mark.hch you are right about the `echo` needing to be outside the `switch` block but more importantly the switch block will never produce a result as the value of `$convertTemp` will not be substituted inside single quotes.

Comment: @Nick I understand that - but the question relates to why the screen is blank, and why the echo is not appearing. The value won't be accurate unless they remove the single-quotes, but that's not causing the issue they were mentioning. If we were able to clear up the `echo`'s location issue, and the script still failed, and they posted a new question stating "The switch is not producing a result" or similar, then I would agree it's a duplicate. However, if this were marked as dupe before I answered, then I would have to clear up the actual issue (blank page) in the comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There were a couple issues here. The `echo` you weren't seeing was in the `switch` statement after the last `break`, when it needed to come after the switch (i.e. after the closing bracket of the `switch` statement). However, even doing that, the variables aren't set (`$tEmp` is not set, you need to get its value from `$_POST` first, same as `$convertTemp`).

```
<?php
  if(isset($_POST['convertTemp']) && isset($_POST['tEmp'])) {
    $convertTemp = $_POST['convertTemp'];
    $tEmp = $_POST['tEmp'];
    switch($convertTemp){
        case 'FtoC':
            $newTemp = (($tEmp - 32)* (5/9));
            break;
        case 'FtoK':
           $newTemp = (($tEmp - 32)* (5/9) + 273.15);
            break;
        case 'KtoF':
           $newTemp = (($tEmp - 273.15)* (9/5) + 32);
            break;
         case 'KtoC':
           $newTemp = ($tEmp - 273.15);
            break;
        case 'CtoK':
           $newTemp = ($tEmp + 273.15);
            break;
        case 'CtoF':
           $newTemp = (($tEmp * 9/5) + 32);
            break;      
    }
    echo "<h2 align='center'>The initial temperature was " . $tEmp . " and the converted temperature is: " . $newTemp . "</h2>";
  }
  else {
    echo'
      <html>
        <body>
          <h1 align="center">Convert a Temperature</h1>
          <form align="center" method="POST">
            Enter the tempurature you wish to convert:<input type="number" name="tEmp">

            <h2>Convert temperature from: </h2>

            <input type="radio" name="convertTemp" value="FtoC"> Farenheit to Celcius <br>
            <input type="radio" name="convertTemp" value="FtoK"> Farenheit to Kelvin <br>
            <input type="radio" name="convertTemp" value="KtoF"> Kelvin to Farenheit <br>
            <input type="radio" name="convertTemp" value="KtoC"> Kelvin to Celcius <br>
            <input type="radio" name="convertTemp" value="CtoK"> Celcius to Kelvin <br>
            <input type="radio" name="convertTemp" value="CtoF"> Celcius to Farenheit <br>

            <input type="submit" value="Convert Tempurature!">
          </form>
        </body>
      </html>
    ';
  }
?>
```

Comment: Thank you so much!! This is exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: Happy to help! If it solved your issue, be sure to accept it as the answer, so people can find it, and so no one else wastes time solving a solved issue. Have a great day!